# Add Category Column Based On Date - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column ORDER_DATE. I'm trying to add a new column for FISCAL_YEAR which essentially has this type of criteria:

- If between 7/1/16 and 6/30/17 = FY2017
- If between 7/1/17 and 6/30/18 = FY2018

The only way I could think to do it is a series of conditional statements, which I am certain is not the most efficient or elegant. While my solution works as intended, it takes forever and I'm hoping for suggestions on how to make it better.

```
    #adds a fiscal year column to purchases
    purchases['FISCAL_YEAR'] = 'N/A'
    purchases['FISCAL_YEAR'][(purchases['ORDER_DATE'] >= dt.datetime.strptime('2017-07-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()) & \
(purchases['ORDER_DATE'] <= dt.datetime.strptime('2018-06-30', "%Y-%m-%d").date())] = 'FY2017'

    purchases['FISCAL_YEAR'][(purchases['ORDER_DATE'] >= dt.datetime.strptime('2017-07-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()) & \
(purchases['ORDER_DATE'] <= dt.datetime.strptime('2018-06-30', "%Y-%m-%d").date())] = 'FY2018'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `PeriodIndex` to the dataframe with a June annual frequency (`A-Jun`), e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2015-01', end='2016-12', freq='D')})
df = df.assign(fiscal_year=pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='A-Jun'))
```

If you need the string representation (e.g. FY2015),

```
df.assign(fiscal_year_str='FY' + df['fiscal_year'].astype(str))
```

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with the functions you're calling upon. I'm not sure what freq = D represents, nor do I understand 'A-Jun.' Can you elaborate?

And to answer your question, I don't absolutely need the string representation, but I do need the specific parameters (EG a 'fiscal year' is defined as 7/1-6/30)

Comment: freq `D` is daily, so that it creates a dataframe of daily dates from 2015-01-01 through 2016-12-01 (701 in total).  I did this to create some data for dates against which I could create the PeriodIndex.  The argument `A-Jun` means annual frequencies taken at June month end, i.e. 7/1-6/30 (if you used `freq='A'`, it would default to `A-Dec`).

Answer (score 0):

```
df['ORDER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDER DATE'])
def fisc_year(x):
    if (x > pd.to_datetime('2016-07-01')) & (x < pd.to_datetime('2017-06-30')):
        return 'FY2017'
    elif (x > pd.to_datetime('2017-07-01')) & (x < pd.to_datetime('2018-06-30')):
        return 'FY2018'
df['FY'] = df['ORDER DATE'].apply(fisc_year)
```